# Django hosting in cpanel with out using Setup Python App

Tags: django, hosting, cpanel

I want to host my Django project in cPanel with out using Setup Python App. How can i do that? Please provide step by step solution from beginning.

I search for the solution in google, but i can't get the answer. Please help me.

Comment: i think it's not possible, you need VPS hosing to deploy django project

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.